# How can I make an Angular directive wait for isolate scope data to be available?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a controller which loads data from my API. Unfortunately I have a scenario where I cannot use a resolve to load the data.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function() {
    var myController = this;

    formService.find('123').then(function(response) {
        myController.formData = response.data;
    });
});
```

My controller's template then uses a directive which uses this data:

```
<form-component form-data="myController.formData"></form-component>
```

And the directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('formComponent', function() {
    'use strict';

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            formData: '=',
        },
        templateUrl: 'formComponent.html',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            // Outputs "undefined" as this is not yet loaded when
            // this directive runs.
            console.log($scope.formData);
        }
    };
});
```

As you can see, when the directive runs, the API has not yet returned with the data, and so $scope.formData is undefined when accessed.

Is there a way I can elegantly somehow make my directive only begin acting on the data when it becomes available? I can think of a couple solutions, but I'm not super happy with any:

1. Broadcast an event indicating data is loaded.
2. Put a $watch in place in the directive and then unbind the watch when the watch callback runs.

Comment: I doubt there is something more elegant than (2) as it stands, so I would go for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leave `formData` falsey (`null`/`undefined` works) until the data loads and use an ng-if. The directive only will compile once ng-if is true.

```
<form-component ng-if="myController.formData" form-data="myController.formData"></form-component>
```

Comment: Super cool! This is one solution that does work! http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/Xktuz/

Comment: @ChadJohnson, but it only works if the user of the directive does that. A properly authored directive still has to be able to deal with `undefined` data, especially if your definition of "acting on the data" means some way of processing it. You'd need to account for a possibility of the user of the directive not using `ng-if`

Comment: That's true. I'm okay with this solution for my scenario, though, I'm still interested in more robust solutions.

Comment: @ChadJohnson, then you should put `ng-if` inside the directive template. But if "acting on data" means start some processing or loading, then your #2 approach is best

Comment: You can simply do the same thing and put the `ng-if` inside the form-data template. Though, I would prefer the pattern of not wasting time compiling the directive in the first place if I don't have the data available, and would probably do it as I first laid out. Faster overall.

Comment: @DylanWatt I may be misunderstanding you, but using ng-if inside the formComponent template does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/5k3rugdn/1/. If you look in the console output, you'll see "undefined." I need $scope.formData to be available in the directive's link() function.

Comment: Ah, I was unaware that you were operating on it in the link function, I thought it was merely a render with null data issue. If you need it in the link, then you would definitely either need to `ng-if` the whole thing, or `$watch` the `formData`.

Comment: `ng-if` is a directive and it adds a $watch. In this case I think it would be safe to use one-time binding (angular 1.3+) on the ng-if, then it'll remove its $watch when formData becomes defined. `ng-if="::myController.formData"`